# Hovers and Dropdown Submenu

Tags: html, css, menu, navigation, submenu

My hovers are seems not working, same is true with the Navigation Sub-menu which is suppose to be a drop down menu. And so with the ul and li elements they are centered now but they are not distributed evenly within the navigation menu - its at the bottom.

What do you think?

Here are the CSS CODES:

```
nav {
    width: 1000px;
    background-color: #CCC;
    padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

nav ul{
    list-style-type: none;
}

nav ul ul{
    display: none;
}


nav ul li{
    float: left;        
}

nav ul a{
    color:#666;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;    
    padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;      
}

nav ul a: hover{
     color: #FFF;
}
```

Here are the HTML CODES:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
        <li>
            <a href="products_and_services.html">PRODUCTS &amp; SERVICES</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="">BROCHURES</a></li>
                <li><a href="">BUSINESS CARDS</a></li>
                <li><a href="">MAGAZINES</a></li>
                <li><a href="">BOOKS</a></li>
                <li><a href="">WEB DESIGN</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="gallery.html">GALLERY</a></li>
        <li><a href="support.html">SUPPORT</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact_us.html">CONTACT US</a></li>
        <li><a href="about_us.html">ABOUT US</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Thanks and more power!

Answer (score 2):

This is the HTML code:

```
<nav>
  <ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">about</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">blogs</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">item a lonng submenu</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Ray</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Veronica</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Bushy</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Havoc</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">media</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">here</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

And the CSS:

```
nav {    
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
  }
  nav ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
    list-style: none;
  }
  .nav a {
    display:block; 
    background: #111; 
    color:#fff; 
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: .8em 1.8em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 80%;letter-spacing: 2px;
    text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #000;
    position: relative;
  }
  .nav{  
    vertical-align: top; 
    display: inline-block;
    box-shadow: 1px -1px -1px 1px #000, -1px 1px -1px 1px #fff, 0 0 6px 3px #fff;
    border-radius:6px;
  }
  .nav li{position: relative;}
  .nav > li { 
    float:left; 
    border-bottom: 4px #aaa solid; 
    margin-right: 1px; 
  } 
  .nav > li > a { 
    margin-bottom:1px;
    box-shadow:inset 0 2em .33em -.5em #555; 
  }
  .nav > li:hover , .nav > li:hover >a{  border-bottom-color:orange;}
  .nav li:hover > a { color:orange; }
  .nav > li:first-child  { border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;} 
  .nav > li:first-child>a{border-radius: 4px 0 0 0;}
  .nav > li:last-child  { 
    border-radius: 0 0 4px 0; 
    margin-right: 0;
  } 
  .nav > li:last-child >a{border-radius: 0 4px 0 0; }
  .nav li li a { margin-top:1px}



    .nav li a:first-child:nth-last-child(2):before { 
     content:""; 
     position: absolute; 
     height:0; 
     width: 0; 
     border: 5px solid transparent; 
     top: 50% ;
     right:5px;  
   }
/* submenu positioning*/
.nav ul {
  position: absolute;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border-bottom: 5px solid  orange;
  z-index: 1;
  left: -99999em;
}
.nav > li:hover > ul {
  left: auto;
  padding-top: 5px  ;
  min-width: 100%;
}
.nav > li li ul {  border-left:1px solid #fff;}
.nav > li li:hover > ul { 
 /* margin-left: 1px */
  left: 100%;
  top: -1px;
}
/* arrow hover styling */
.nav > li > a:first-child:nth-last-child(2):before { 
  border-top-color: #aaa; 
}
.nav > li:hover > a:first-child:nth-last-child(2):before {
  border: 5px solid transparent; 
  border-bottom-color: orange; 
  margin-top:-5px
}
.nav li li > a:first-child:nth-last-child(2):before {  
  border-left-color: #aaa; 
  margin-top: -5px
}
.nav li li:hover > a:first-child:nth-last-child(2):before {
  border: 5px solid transparent; 
  border-right-color: orange;
  right: 10px; 
}
```

Comment: You should probably try and explain your answer

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `display block` to submenu onhover of parent li

```
 nav ul ul {
        display: none;
        position:absolute;
        width:150px;
    }
    nav ul a:hover {
        color: #FFF;
    }
    nav ul li:hover ul {
        display:block;
        }
   nav ul li {
        display: inline-block;
   }
```

**[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6qJwn/1/)**

Comment: This one really works. Though, I still have problem distributing those elements evenly at the navigation bar. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the space from the following:

```
nav ul a: hover{
```

Code should look like:

```
nav ul a:hover{
```

See the example: http://jsfiddle.net/b7424/

Comment: Mark, Thanks! By the way, I thought spaces don't matter to back-end codes - does spaces matter?

Comment: Like most languages white space normally moves onto the "next" "command"

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the space from a: hover use a:hover then it will work